# How will centralized portions of the Ethereum space (Infura, EtherScan) respond to huge increases in throughput?

Tags: nodes, decentralization

Two forthcoming improvements to Ethereum are Casper and Sharding. While FFG Casper won't decrease the 14-second block time (because it's hybrid POS/POW), full-fledged Casper promises to. Sharding holds the promise of increasing transactions per second (and block production per second) many times over that.

Given the recent overloading of the Ethereum ecosystem in the light of  Cryptokitties, etc., (part of which was due to the overloading of centralized systems such as Infura, EtherScan, and MyEtherWallet) how are these 'centralizing' influences planning on handling the impending massive increase in activity when the changes come into effect?

Shouldn't we all be pretty concerned about this given the heavy reliance on these heavily centralized systems? Would encouraging a much more decentralized stance (i.e. everyone running their own nodes) help?

Comment: "part of which was due to the overloading centralized systems such as Infura, EtherScan, and MyEtherWallet" Could you provide a citation for that? What exactly happened to those three tools?

Comment: I don’t have a citation. But I would say tweets telling people to communicate with Infura that they’re about to do an ICO is an indication that Infura needs to prepare themselves for an increase in traffic. Similar tweets from MyEtherWallet and Metamask.

Comment: MetaMask isn't a website and doesn't have any servers... what sort of scaling could they need to do? MyEtherWallet is static content served from a CDN, so surely they can handle much more traffic than even all Ethereum users browsing to them at the same time. Infura is the only thing I could imagine needing to scale.

Comment: Meta ask defaults to Infura. Also, based on tweets admittedly, MyEtherWallet defaults to their own nodes. (But that is speculation). In any case, I asked on Gitter if the recent problems were node related or centralizing influenced related. Answer was both. Again no citation.